# how to set text color in list view in android app

Tags: android, listview, text, colors

in my app i have created a list view and added some text in the list. In my coding part the text are been added as an array adapter to have a check box. In the layout i have given a white color for the list view because of this the text appear to be very dull. How to set the text color to be as black.

Comment: i have given as array adapter with checked box....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text is added as a part of a TextView, you should be able to call setTextColor(int) on it.

Answer (score 1):

set the text color in your xml

`< TextView

 android:id="@+id/list_content"

 android:textColor="#000000"

 android:gravity="center"

 android:text="sample"

 android:layout_margin="4dip"

 android:layout_width="fill_parent"

 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 />`

Comment: i have given as array adapter with checked box and so i have not create a textview in layout....

Comment: Why is it that the android cannot identify textColor resource?